# How to add a date column which is 7 days later than an existing column in a Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database table which has two date columns (i.e. `from_date` and `to_date`). The `from_date` column has data, but the `to_date` is `null`. I want to add dates in `to_date` column to be exactly 7 days later than the `from_date`.
Is this possible in Postgres?

The link provided for the duplicate of my post is so sophisticated and provides a solution for wide range of problems. I found my answer in Google. All I needed was a simple update:

```
UPDATE records
SET to_datetime=from-datetime;
UPDATE records
SET to_datetime = to_datetime + interval '7 day';
```

Comment: Create a view that returns that information, it's usually not necessary to store information that can easily be derived from existing data

Comment: I need the column to be present in the database

Comment: If you use a view it's "present" in the database as well. Do you plan to update the column to a different value at some time?

Comment: No. I plan to keep it as it is after I get the 7 days later data. I am using the table in a python django project which requires the column `to_date` to be there and be exactly 7 days later. For the sake of complication it could bring I am not able to change the python code for now.

Comment: you can still use a view for that.

Comment: I am kind of new to PSQL. Can you help me more on that? How exactly can I do this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your response. The post you provided for the duplicate of this post is very sophisticated. I am sure it does solve some related problems with a wider range, but I don't understand how it can help me.